# DataGridView - scrolling to bottom triggers auto scrolling

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm using a DataGridView for a VSPackage tool window, WinForms style.
I'm using virtual mode since I have a very large data-set to display (`CellValueNeeded` is subscribed and handled appropriately).

The number of rows and columns to be displayed is determined only at run-time, so I use a paging mechanism to display only small parts of the data, e.g.

```
// initialization of the view
DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
dgv.RowCount = 100;
dgv.ColumnCount = 50;
```

So the user sees the first 100 rows of the data, and when he scrolls down, I have an event handling method that increments the RowsCount to display more data:

```
    private void dataGridView_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView.RowCount += 100;
    }
```

But, the problem is that **the scrolling bar goes crazy after I draw it to the bottom,** it repeatedly scrolls-down on its own behalf even though I dragged it only once and I was idle with the mouse.

It's like i'm in an infinite loop of scrolling that triggers another scrolling, feels like a big events mess.

How can I prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried entering a breakpoint after you add the rows?

```
private void dataGridView_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView.RowCount += 100;
    break;
}
```